# Execute a DELETE command whilst iterating through an XML input parameter

Tags: sql-server, loops, nodes, sql-delete

I have a stored procedure that receives 2 parameters.

```
@username VARCHAR(8), 
@xmlShiftDays XML
```

I want to delete multiple rows from the database while iterating through the XML.

I have managed to do something similar for an INSERT (see below)

```
INSERT INTO table(username, date)
   SELECT 
       username = @username, 
       CONVERT(DATETIME,shiftDate.date.value('.','VARCHAR(10)'),103)
   FROM 
       @xmlShiftDays.nodes('/shiftDates/date') as shiftDate(date)
```

This will successfully insert "x" amount of rows into my table.

I now want to re-engineer the query to `DELETE` "x" amount of rows. If anyone knows how or could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

An example of what I want to achieve is:

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @xmlShiftDays XML 

SET @xmlShiftDays = '<shiftDates><date>21/01/2012</date></shiftDates>'
SET @username = 'A0123456'

DELETE FROM table
WHERE username = @username
AND date = "<b>loop through the nodes in the XML string</b>"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server **2008** (or newer) for this so I can use the `DATE` datatype (unfortunately, you didn't specify in your question which version of SQL Server you're using).....

I would **strongly** recommend you use a language-independent, regional-settings-independent date format in your XML - use the ISO-8601 format of `YYYYMMDD` for best results.

So try something like this:

```
DECLARE @xmlShiftDays XML 

SET @xmlShiftDays = '<shiftDates><date>20120122</date><date>20120227</date></shiftDates>'

;WITH DatesToDelete AS
(
    SELECT
        DeletionDate = DT.value('(.)[1]', 'date')
    FROM @XmlShiftDays.nodes('/shiftDates/date') AS SD(DT)
)
SELECT * FROM DatesToDelete
```

This should give you the two dates combined into XML string - right?

Now, you can use this to do the deletion from your table:

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @xmlShiftDays XML 

SET @xmlShiftDays = '<shiftDates><date>20120122</date><date>20120227</date></shiftDates>'
SET @username = 'A0123456'

;WITH DatesToDelete AS
(
    SELECT
        DeletionDate = DT.value('(.)[1]', 'date')
    FROM @XmlShiftDays.nodes('/shiftDates/date') AS SD(DT)
)
DELETE FROM dbo.Table
WHERE username = @username
AND date IN (SELECT DeletionDate FROM DatesToDelete)
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Im not using SQL 2008, im using 2005, but other than using the DATE datatype, your solution worked perfectly.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the date from the Xml in the same way you did for the Insert:

```
    DELETE FROM table
    WHERE username = @username
    AND date IN (SELECT 
           CONVERT(DATETIME,shiftDate.date.value('.','VARCHAR(10)'),103)
       FROM 
           @xmlShiftDays.nodes('/shiftDates/date') as shiftDate(date))
```